# text animation on thumbs

Tags: css, background, css-transitions

im trying to create a download page with box thumbs
where the description text come from the right side
when the mouse is on the thumb

i did almost everything ive still to format with

but text appear outside the 100*100px box and i dont know what
i'm missing, i would see just the animation in the box.

any advice ?

tnx

this is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">

    div.div0 {
    background:url('t_k1.png');
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    }
    div.div1 {
    opacity:0;
    display:block;
    left:100px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#999;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:-50px;
    }
    div.div0:hover div.div1 {
    animation:mymove 2s forwards;
    -moz-animation:mymove 2s forwards;
    -webkit-animation:mymove 2s forwards;
    -o-animation:mymove 2s forwards;
    }

    @keyframes mymove {
    from {left:100px; opacity:0;}
    to {left:0px; opacity:0.8;}
    }

    @-moz-keyframes mymove /*Firefox*/ {
    from {left:100x; opacity:0;}
    to {left:0px; opacity:0.8;}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes mymove /*Safari and Chrome*/ {
    from {left:100px; opacity:0;}
    to {left:0px; opacity:0.8;}
    }

    @-o-keyframes mymove /*Opera*/ {
    from {left:100px; opacity:0;}
    30% {opacity:0.2;}
    to {left:0px; opacity:0.8;}
    }

    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="display:block; left:100px; top:100px; width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute;">
    <div class="div0">
    <div class="div1"><br /><br /><a href="#">prova</a></div>
    </div></div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A97cc/

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A97cc/1

to prevent an element from beeing visible outside its parent, you have the set the overfow to hidden on the parent, div0 in your case.